# Attach to docker remote debug linux module from vs2019 fails to load/install VSDBG on Linux target

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio-2019, ubuntu-20.04, azure-iot-edge

I'm attempting to remote debug a linux module running on docker. Following this article works for a simple test project.
[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/iotdev/debug-azure-iot-edge-c-remote-linux-module-container-with-visual-studio-2019-version-16-3/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu1K2.png)

When I attempt to attach to the module that is setup via SSH with root login permissions enabled, I get this output from Visual Studio:

[image]

VSDBG is **not** installed on my linux target so whats failing is the download/setup of VSDBG.  I found a related article on installing VSDBG manually that references the //.vs-debugger path but I'm not sure if this is what is needed
https://www.plcnext-community.net/en/hn-makers-blog/464-remote-debugging-of-a-net-core-application-with-vs-code-on-plcnext.html

I noticed when I select the module to debug that the User Name show "nobody" instead of what I think is normal/expected which is "moduleUser".  Is this related to the issue?

[image]

So I'm looking for help understanding why the download and install of VSDBG is failing.  The SSH credentials are using root so I don't think permissions should be a problem.  On the other hand, the failure is simple and possibly permission related:

> Command 'mkdir -p '//.vs-debugger'' failed with code '1'. "

If there is a manual set of steps I can follow to install VSDBG so my visual studio attach-to-debug works, as shown above, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you follow Prerequisites stated here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-visual-studio-develop-module?view=iotedge-2020-11#prerequisites

Comment: @asegaz, yes, i used this document to setup and test a single module.  I was able to debug the module proving my windows environment is configured correctly.  When I attempt to debug a module I did not create myself, i get the errors described above.

Comment: I believe this case relates with yours, can you followup there with the Visual Studio Team? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Issue-while-attaching-visual-studio-atta/1474539?space=8&q=Attach+to+docker+remote+debug+linux+module+from+vs2019+fails+to+load%2Finstall+VSDBG+on+Linux+target&sort=relevance